# Ajax post comment like StackOverflow

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My question is, what is better way to do comments system like on StackOverflow,
I mean I send request from my browser and everybody will see this comment (or in other browser) without refreshing page like some chat.

My solution was to use `setInterval`, but I think there must be another way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
get();
$('#send').click(function() {
    $.post('http://localhost/mvc.com/comment/post', {
        n_id: parseInt(newsId),
        user_id: $('#uid').val(),
        text: $('#content').val(),
        token: $('#token').val()
    }, function (ret) {
        if (ret.comm.err) {
            $('.f').empty().prepend('<li id=e><h3 style="color: red">ERROR</h3></li>');
            return false;
        }
        get();
    });
    setInterval(get,3000);
});

$('#content').keypress(function(e){
    var key = e.which;
    var cnt=$(this).val().length;
    var max=100;
    var tot=parseInt(max-cnt);
    if(key >= 33 || key == 13 || key == 32) {
        if (parseInt(tot) <= 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});

function get() {
    $.post('http://localhost/mvc.com/comment', {get: parseInt(newsId)}, function (ret) {
        $('.f').empty();
        for (var key in ret.comm) {
            $('.f').append('<li class=c id=' + ret.comm[key].id +
            '><span>' + ret.comm[key].name + '</span><hr><br>' + ret.comm[key].text + '</li>');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets) is a nicer solution than setInterval.

Comment: Adding `setInterval` without clearing previous one on every `#send` sounds like dangerous idea. `var tot = parseInt(max - cnt);` instead of simple `var tot = max - cnt;` looks strange. `parseInt(tot) <= 0` instead of `tot <= 0` also is strange.

Comment: If you are familiar with .Net technologies, try it in SignalR provides good solutions for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I have seen your aforementioned approach being used for real time updates but it is not the correct way to do it.

You will need to use web sockets which are the de facto for real time web applications.

Web sockets are a subject in itself and I can keep going but here is a link to get you started on them: http://socketo.me

Answer (score 2):

You don't need setInterval. What you can do is so called long polling:

**Javascript**: you define ajax function that is calling itself on complete:

```
function poll(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(msg){
            update_poll(msg);//here you update your span, div, whatever what contains this comment
        },
        dataType: "text",
        complete: function(){
            poll();//here you call it again
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    poll();//call it just once
});
```

**PHP**: you start a one minute loop, which checks every 3 seconds for the new entry in your database:

```
if(isset($_POST['n_id'])){
    $n_id = (int) $_POST['n_id'];
    $time = time();
    while((time() - $time) < 60) {
       $last entry = get_last_entry($n_id);
       if($last entry){
           echo $last_entry;//if found new entry, echo it out and break the loop
           break;
       }
        sleep(3);//wait 3 seconds
    }
}
```

Comment: Request, which hangs for minute? Not a good idea, you know. For example, you might have 30 secongs request's timeout. Additionally, It consumes more server resources due to `while`. You also can't change something related to requests (extra-force update or changed request parameters or interval)  on client side during request with this approach.

Comment: @Regent Nothing is perfect, but I have been using it for years and it works OK, that's the simplest way.

Comment: But "it works" does not mean that it is good (I don't talk about perfect) way. Let's imagine that you want to check whether you have new mails in your mailbox or not. Instead of checking it once in a day, you stays whole day near mailbox, and it rechecks for new mails every hour. Does it sound "OK"? Do you want to stay near mailbox whole your day?

Comment: @Regent Frankly I use it only for myself for checking registry entries of the users' actions in my application, which appear every few seconds, so it flashes constantly. I don't know what is OP's application. Also I can check for several different changes in this one loop by the way, even for new emails.